# How can I deserialize a Soap Message myself inside a C# Web Service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, server

I want to deserialize the xml message from a Post Event in a C# Web Service before it is handled by the WebService Method.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Comment: It's not about the deserialization directly, I just want to do it myself, I don't know how to do it. how can I intercept everything the webserver receives before it is forwarded to the automatism of the web service model. My soap request probably has a special header that is rejected by the web service with 
the http error 400 Bad Request. Unfortunately I can't even evaluate the soap request myself.

Comment: I guess the service is setup in the configuration file.  So the class where the event is handled you need to override to capture the message before is handled in the Webservice.